# change checkbox label background size in html

Tags: html, checkbox, label

I'd like to know if it's possible to change the size of an html checkbox label background (mines have quite a broad vertical range around the text), or is that irremediably linked to font size ?

Any help will be gladly received,
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

html

```
<div class="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Test" id="test1"><label for "test1" class="highlight">Test_button</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.checkboxes label {
    font-family:Arial Black;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 100px 4px;
    text-align: left;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    color: white;
    background: #F2B611;           
                                       }
```